# How to set IndexColorModel in Buffered image to have certain colors and one transparent?

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage

I am trying to draw a bar that shows a quality of something.

I created a buffered image like this:

```
 private static BufferedImage createBufferedImage(int width, int height) {
        int[] palette = {0x00ff00ff, 0xffff00ff, 0xff0000ff , 0xffff0000};
        IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(2, 4,
            palette, 0, true, 0, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        return new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED, colorModel);
    }
```

The colorModel should have colors: green, yellow, red and one transparent.
The color of bar depends on the quality like this:

```
 private static Color getBarColor(double quality) {
        if (quality >= 0.70) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        } else if (quality >= 0.40) {
            return Color.YELLOW;
        } else {
            return Color.RED;
        }
    }
```

Im creating graphics'to draw the bar and set the color:

```
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
g.setColor(getBarColor(quality));
```

However, when I set the color for quality bigger than 0.7 it draws blue bar, and for quality lower than 0.7 id draws red.

I think that the problem is in my pallete, that I am not setting the colors right and when I'm trying to get green color and it is not there the closest possible is set. I think format RRGGBBAA should be used where AA set transparency with ff being not transparent and 00 being transparent.Do I understand it correctly? Where is the problem?

I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you assume the alpha is the part at the lower bits of the integer you feed into the palette. In fact, it's ARGB, not RGBA.

You can test this with a simple loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    int red = colorModel.getRed(i);
    int green = colorModel.getGreen(i);
    int blue = colorModel.getBlue(i);
    int alpha = colorModel.getAlpha(i);

    System.out.printf("For index %d, red=%d, green=%d, blue=%d, alpha=%d%n", i,red,green,blue,alpha);
}
```

The result will be:

```
For index 0, red=255, green=0, blue=255, alpha=0
For index 1, red=255, green=0, blue=255, alpha=255
For index 2, red=0, green=0, blue=255, alpha=255
For index 3, red=255, green=0, blue=0, alpha=255
```

Now, if you want the colors to be green, yellow, red and transparent yellow, you should use:

```
int[] palette = { 0xff00ff00, 0xffffff00, 0xffff0000, 0x00ffff00 };
```

But you should note that you have also told it to take the first pixel value as transparent instead of the last. Your color model creation should be:

```
IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(2,         // bits per pixel
                                                 4,         // size of color component array
                                                 palette,   // color map
                                                 0,         // offset in the map
                                                 true,      // has alpha
                                                 3,         // the pixel value that should be transparent
                                                 DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
```

When you do that, if you run the loop above again, you'll get the results:

```
For index 0, red=0, green=255, blue=0, alpha=255
For index 1, red=255, green=255, blue=0, alpha=255
For index 2, red=255, green=0, blue=0, alpha=255
For index 3, red=255, green=255, blue=0, alpha=0
```

In fact, it would be much more straightforward if you don't use alpha in the palette values at all, since you want to indicate transparency only in one particular value. For this, set the `hasAlpha` parameter to `false` rather than `true`:

```
int[] palette = { 0x00ff00, 0xffff00, 0xff0000, 0xffff00 };
IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(2,
                                                 4,
                                                 palette,
                                                 0,
                                                 false,
                                                 3,
                                                 DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
```

This will give you the same result, but it's much easier to read and predict the results.

Comment: It's worth noting that you should *either* set `alpha` to `true` and have the alpha values in the color map (the colors can have any level of translucency for `Transparency.TRANSLUCENT`) and leave `transparentIndex` to `-1`, *or* set alpha  `false` and specify a single transparent index (`Transparency.BITMASK`), which will disregard the color in the map for that index. Doing both is just confusing. ;-)

Comment: @haraldK It's not illegal to do so, but I agree that it would be more fitting to do it only if you actually wanted one or more of the other colors to have some transparency. I edited my answer to include an option with `false`.